# What image and message use in the "Not found" page (404 error page)

Tags: website-design, web-app, error-message, notification

I've seen the robot of Google, the creature that has Github. I think that is question of imagination and what kind of data manages your web app to design a custom image and the message to show to the user for the 404 error.

I would like to see other examples or if you got some design ideas about it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are also technical points: 1) Return an actual 404 code 2) Don't do a redirect. Redirects on error are extremely annoying as a user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit like saying - *can you just type **404 page examples** into Google for me and summarise the results for me too*. Try doing this and you get a bunch of pages like [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/08/17/404-error-pages-reloaded/) and [that](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/29/404-error-pages-one-more-time/) on Smashing Magazine and just a whole load of other collections.

But there's more to presenting a 404 page than a funny picture - A List part has a good article on [The Perfect 404](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/perfect404/)

> 404 Must-haves
>
> As well as the “something went wrong” text, you should ensure that
>   your error page has the following:
>
> - A link to the site map (if you have one) and the home page. This is
>     the easiest way for users to bail out. This no-brainer requires no
>     clever scripting.
> - A search box. If you have a site search, add it to your 404 page.
>     If you don’t have a site search and are in the habit of generating 404
>     errors, perhaps you should get one.
> - A distinctly minimalist look. Avoid putting all your standard site
>     navigation on this page. You should aim to remove distractions.
>     Besides, insisting on including a complete site navigation strip may
>     present a maintentance overhead (your 404 page can easily lag behind
>     the rest of the site if it is not dynamically updated with the rest of
>     your site and the last thing you want is to have navigation on the 404
>     that is no longer relevant/working. Oh the irony!)
>
> Also be sure to cut the jargon. I mean, we can talk about 404s here,
>   right? We’re in good company. But 60-year-old Doris who got a broken
>   link while browsing a knitting site won’t have a clue what a 404 error
>   is. If you want to use the phrase “Error 404,” do it subtly — do it as
>   a footnote, a nod to those who understand your freaky-deaky web speak.

**So here's a comparison of what not to do, and what to do:**

Here's my favourite humerous one - and I'll assume that Lorem Ipsum is ironic (but I wonder what real book they could have used instead). *But it's absolutely totally useless*. It's a complete dead end.

[image]

And here's an example one from [Bergan Blue](http://www.berganblue.com.au/404) that's not amazingly funny, but is actually truly useful in terms of forwarding the visitor on to another page.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

this is a 404 for a gas company that is allways there when u r on the road.
[www.petrol.si/404/](http://www.petrol.si/404/) we used a deadend street. and we are actually selling the garmin gadget in this context :)

[image]

Comment: "a gas company that is allways there when u r on the road" What on Earth is that supposed to mean? Do you mean they do a lot of billboard advertising on roadsides?

Comment: Oh. I've just worked out you meant *gas* in the American sense: petrol. And you mean it's a fuel company with a lot of filling stations. I think.